# Merge tables in ascending order in R in one line

Tags: r, sorting, merge

I'm trying to merge two tables in ascending order. So that the id would start from 2. However, the order does not change by sort. The command should be in one line.

```
`table1 <- data.table(id=c("16", "20", "21", "22", "6", "11", "24", "15", "2", "12"), 
                   CreditCard=c("2683823637999175", "4247141693495656", "4738525373795814",
                                "6742834456721264", "4339355365311879", "4994262737933115",
                                "9236461982785987", "8816152893421623", "4858583523675652",
                                "8589458131346557"),
                   CVV=c("756", "656", "575", "356", "498", "832", "418", "811", "267","597"),
                   type=c("r", "i", "i", "o", "l", "l", "i", "l", "i", "o"))

table2 <- data.table(firstName=c("Marcos", "Aaron", "Alan", "Alexis", "Lacrae", "Shanelle",
                               "Meeso", "Charles", "Yvonne", "Priscilla", "Jessica"),
                   lastName=c("Recinos Peraza", "Santistevan", "Vigil", "Debora", 
                              "Mccoy", "Walters", "Hwang", "Panyachith", "Strader",
                              "Poonpiset", "Serna"),
                   customer_id=c("6", "11", "24", "15", "2", "12", "5", "9", "4", "10", "23"))

merged <- merge(table1, table2, all=TRUE, by.x = 'id', by.y = 'customer_id')`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The column 'id' is `character`, so we can do an `order` on the `numeric` converted 'id' after the `merge`

```
merged <- merge(table1, table2, all=TRUE, by.x = 'id', 
       by.y = 'customer_id')[order(as.numeric(id))]
```